# Select unique values

Tags: r

I need to change this function that doesn't match for unique values. For example, if I want MAPK4, the function matches MAPK41 and AMAPK4 etc. The function must select only the unique values.

Function:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(mutated = paste(mutated_genes[unlist(
    lapply(mutated_genes, function(x) grepl(x,genes, ignore.case = T)))], collapse=","),
    circuit_name = gsub("", "", circuit_name)) %>%
  select(-genes) %>%
  data.frame()
```

data:

```
df <-structure(list(circuit_name = c("hsa04010__117", "hsa04014__118" ), genes = c("MAP4K4,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP3*,DUSP3*,DUSP3*,DUSP3*,PPM1A,AKT3,AKT3,AKT3,ZAK,MAP3K12,MAP3K13,TRAF2,CASP3,IL1R1,IL1R1,TNFRSF1A,IL1A,IL1A,TNF,RAC1,RAC1,RAC1,RAC1,MAP2K7,MAPK8,MAPK8,MAPK8,MECOM,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,MAP4K3,MAPK8IP2,MAP4K1",  "MAP4K4,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -2L))  
mutated_genes <- c("MAP4K4", "MAP3K12","TRAF2", "CACNG3")
```

output:

```
  circuit_name      mutated
1  hsa04010__117 MAP4K4,TRAF2
2  hsa04014__118       MAP4K4
```

Comment: It seems that `genes` column is collapsed and when you use grep it will return whole line.

Comment: how about `!duplicated`? returns a logical vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R approach would be by splitting the `genes` on "," and return those string which match `mutated_genes`.

```
df$mutated <- sapply(strsplit(df$genes, ","), function(x) 
   toString(grep(paste0(mutated_genes, collapse = "|"), x, value = TRUE)))

df[c(1, 3)]
#   circuit_name                mutated
#1 hsa04010__117 MAP4K4, MAP3K12, TRAF2
#2 hsa04014__118                 MAP4K4
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please note that based on the `mutated_genes` vector, your expected output is missing `MAP3K12` for `hsa04010__117`.**

Here is a `tidyverse` possibility

```
df %>%
    separate_rows(genes) %>%
    filter(genes %in% mutated_genes) %>%
    group_by(circuit_name) %>%
    summarise(mutated = toString(genes))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  circuit_name  mutated
#  <chr>         <chr>
#1 hsa04010__117 MAP4K4, MAP3K12, TRAF2
#2 hsa04014__118 MAP4K4
```

Explanation: We separate comma-separated entries into different rows, then select only those rows where `genes %in% mutated_genes` and summarise results per `circuit_name` by concatenating `genes` entries.

---

PS. Personally I'd recommend keeping the data in a tidy long format (i.e. don't concatenate entries with `toString`); that way you have one row per gene, which will make any post-processing of the data much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
df$mutated <- sapply(str_extract_all(df$genes, paste(mutated_genes, 
         collapse="|")), toString)
```